# How to create an RPM package which on installing just copies files to specific folders?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I want to create an RPM package consisting of certain files which needs to be copied to different locations upon installation of the RPM.
Please help me out with the spec file

Answer (score 1):

```
vim yourapp.spec
```

This - when run on nonexisting file - will open template for new spec file.

Then in %install section put:

```
install -m 755 -d %{buildroot}/some/directory
cp -a some files %{buildroot}/some/directory
```

and in %files section put:

```
%files
/some/directory
```